# Original iPad, CSS3 transforms, and limitations on imaging caused by RAM

Tags: css, ios, ipad, resolution, ram

I've found some very weird quirks to the original iPad on iOS 5.0.1, and they seem to be effected by the amount of images loaded into the browser at a time.

I've found things rendered at half resolution or less.  (This does not happen on the iPad 2 and reducing images loaded in the background has reduce some of these glitches)

Are there any ways to prioritize elements for RAM storage or rendering?

Answer (score -2):

Preloading images in javascript might do the trick, lookup:

http://elouai.com/javascript-preload-images.php

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I'm going to have to give this a downvote.  You clearly didn't read that this is an issue caused by RAM limitations present on the original iPad but not the iPad 2.  Like I, I already removed preloading to attempt a remedy for this and it helped some.